# ¿Como saber si mi usuario pierde la conexion a internet?

Tags: javascript, axios, navegador-web

Vi que hay todo foro de discusión sobre este tema.

No encontré una respuesta que me no me satisface pues creo que es incompleta he imprecisa. Esa respuesta es esta:

```js
    
    window.addEventListener('offline', goOffline());
    window.addEventListener('online', goOnline());
    
    function goOnline() {
        document.body.classList.remove('offline');
        document.body.classList.add('online');
        document.getElementsByClassName('online')[0].style.display = "block";
      
    }
    
    function goOffline() {
        document.body.classList.remove('online');
        document.body.classList.add('online');
        document.getElementsByClassName('offline')[0].style.display = "block";
    }
    
    if(navigator.onLine) {
        goOnline();
    } else {
       goOffile();
    }
```

```html
 <div class="offline" style="display:none">
  No hay conexión a internet
</div>

 <div class="online" style="display:none">
  conectado a internet
 </div>
```

Cuando se ejecuta el código, sin embargo no es una buena solución y la complemente así.

```js
window.addEventListener('offline', goOffline());
window.addEventListener('online', goOnline());
 
function goOnline() {
  if(testConnect()){
    document.getElementsByClassName('online')[0].style.display = 'block';
    document.body.classList.remove('online');
    document.body.classList.add('online');            
  }else{
    goOffline();
  } 
}
        
function goOffline() {
  document.body.classList.remove('offline');
  document.body.classList.add('offline');
  document.getElementsByClassName('offline')[0].style.display = "block";
  
 }
        
function testConnect(){
  let test = true;
  axios.get('https://search.twitter.com/').then(
    (res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      if(res.status == 200){
        test = true;
      }
    }
  );
  return test;
}
        
if(navigator.onLine) {
  goOnline();
} else {
 goOffile();
}
```

```html
<script src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>

<div class="offline" style="display:none">
      No hay conexión a internet
    </div>

     <div class="online" style="display:none">
      conectado a internet
     </div>
```

Pero sigo sin estar contento. Alguien sabe de alguna forma de hacerlo sin tanto embrollo. No puedo utilizar websockets porque no tengo servidores tan buenos como para mantener a la cantidad de usuarios que tengo. Pero por el tipo de mi aplicación. Si necesito notificarle a mi usuario cuando pierda la conexión con el servidor.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Los eventos `online` y `offline` te indican cuando pierdes conexión a Internet (por ende a tu servidor), pero no te indican si pierdes conexión sólo con tu servidor. En tu pregunta dices: ***necesito notificarle a mi usuario cuando pierda la conexión con el servidor***. Por lo tanto, considero que la solución la debes implementar de alguna manera en tu servidor. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, estar `online` con tu servidor indica mantener un canal abierto entre cliente y servidor. Usar `sockets` sería lo apropiado, pero dices que no lo puedes implementar por temas de capacidad. La pregunta es, ¿porqué necesitas que el cliente se mantenga `online`? ¿Será que estás confundiendo el término?

Comment: Mis usuarios hacen registro en linea. Este registro funciona por medio de una SPA. El problema es que cuando se quedan sin internet pueden seguir contestando. Hasta que intenta actualizar se dan cuenta que no tenían internet y por ende no guardaron nada de lo que contestaron